# How to add 'Ext.require' in Sencha Architect 2 for more than one item?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect

How to add 'Ext.require' in Sencha Architect 2 for more than one item?

In the application node I have a required field, but it allow me only to include one item, e.g., Ext.data.proxy.JsonP

What should I do to add more than one item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you enter a single requires directly below it there will be an empty space with the text "(add another)".

Answer (score 0):

You can also always pass in an object or array of values. This is especially handy for when transcoding / integrating some extension or code into your app when there's no copy & paste import.